# How much service amps do you need for one 400 amp panel (House) and one 200amp panel (shop) on the same meter?

Tags: service

- 400 amp main with two 200 amp sub panels (**House**)
- 200 amp main with one 200 amp sub panel (**Shop**)

How much service amperage do you need for two 200 amp panels (House) and two 200amp panel (shop) on the same meter?

Comment: 600 amps or a load calculation. What are your loads? Square footage? Take the [tour], [edit] your post to include loading info.

Comment: If you are really talking about 600 amps of service, that's getting to the commercial arena.   You'll need to work with your power company for proper provisioning, knowing power companies, that could get very expensive.

Comment: Can you post the square footages of your house and shop, as well as who you have for an electric utility, for starters?

Comment: Often the only affordable way to get this done, IF you really need that much power (which you have not clarified yet) is separate meters (and services) for the house and shop - but that increases your monthly baseline cost without any power used.

Comment: 12000 sq ft house

Comment: 5400 sq ft shop with out buildings

Comment: 2 200 amp sub panels in the house

Comment: Already did the load calculations for my house.

Comment: Trying to avoid 2 meters